# Trigger liquibase rollback during deployment error

Tags: mysql, database, spring-boot, liquibase

We are working on a spring boot application which uses liquibase to manage incremental db changes.

When we encounter any error that stops our deployment from proceeding further, executed liquibase changes remain in database even though the images in the containers gets rolled back to the last working state.

I know that there are liquibase commands to rollback changesets but I was wondering if there are any ways to make liquibase automatically rollback all the changes it made during deployment if any error occurs.

Apologies if this question is very vague. Please let me know if I can provide some more inputs to make the question more clear. We are using mysql database if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the functionality to automatically rollback changes when Liquibase encounters a problem doesn't exist, but it would be a great suggestion for our Idea Board: https://ideas.liquibase.com